# Using VBA in Catia for selection and changing and attribute

Tags: vba, feature-selection, catia

I'm attempting to change attributes in Catia on an active selection only. I'm looking to take this code and generalize it so that instead of targeting 1 specific item, it will activate the macro on whatever item I have selected.

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim documents1 As Documents
    Set documents1 = CATIA.Documents

    Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
    Set partDocument1 = documents1.Item("Test 1.CATPart")

    Dim product1 As product
    Set product1 = partDocument1.GetItem("Test 1")

    product1.Revision = "test"

    product1.Definition = "yo"

End Sub
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question...

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim objSel As Selection
    Set objSel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection

    objSel.Item(1).Value.ATTRIBUTE = "hi"

End Sub
```

This changes the desired attributes of the selected item.